# Pycharm add excluded folder back

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Such as: 
It can not show tip`Member.objects` when I type `Member.o`.(`Member` is a django model)
And same with python build-in function, like `for`,`filter`, `map` and so on.

This feature worked yesterday, I don't know why it broken now.
I have tried `Invalidate Caches / Restart`, do not work.

**UPDATE**

Maybe I know what is the problem.
I have a big folder name `ALL project`, it is my project. and `project A` under `ALL project`.
I accidentally mark `project A` excluded. And I use `File` -> `Open ..` to add it back.
It seems pycharm create `.idea` folder under `project A`, it means pycharm treat `project A` as a project.I have to set `Project Interpreter` for `project A` in order to  get  auto-completion back.

I don't want pycharm treat `project A` as a project. I want it treat `project A` as a folder, then it would use the `Project Interpreter` of `ALL project`.

Ok, I find that `Project Structure dialog` in `File | Settings | Project Structure` .
 Adding the folder back make every thing fine.

Comment: In your project settings, `django support` is still on?
Maybe it's off now

Comment: @coldmind How do I view project settings?

Comment: `File > Settings`. First block is project settings, below is IDE settings. But i did not mentioned that your all autocomplete is off.
Go to `IDE Settings > Editor > Code completion`. Maybe something off there.

Comment: @coldmind All autocomplete is on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set project interpreter correctly, i also had this problem when i started using pycharm, it can be also because of your editor settings file>editor>code-completion.